# xUnit: How run additional code in case of failure

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm using xUnit for UI testing w/ Selenium. I like to take a screenshot in case of failure. Is it possible to do such final work before termination?

Comment: Hi, you asked this question about a year ago. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know some official way. But my idea is to wrap your assert to some method where you can handle failure

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        int expected = 1;

        int result = 1 + 1;

        HandleAssert(() => Assert.Equal(expected, result));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        int expected = 2;

        int result = 1 + 1;

        HandleAssert(() => Assert.Equal(expected, result));
    }

    private void HandleAssert(Action assert)
    {
        try
        {
            assert.Invoke();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //make screenshot
            //just throw for preserve stacktrace
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already do that. I basically pass a lambda expression to an exception handler. But this isn't elegant.

Comment: @robie2011, please, define _elegant_

Comment: I like to write tests that are consise without any ceremonial code. An xunit attribute on testmethod or testclass level would be very useful in such case. There is for example a BeforeAfterAttribute. But unfortunatly I don't see anyway to access test result to react on failing result.